# jQuery checkbox won't update

Tags: jquery, checkbox, dynamic, edit

Here's my html:

```
<tr>
    <td class="tg-031e"><input type="checkbox" name="sel_a" class="a_qual" data-id23="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"
    <?php if($row["a_qual"] == 1) { echo "checked='1'"; } ?>
    ></td>
    <td class="a" colspan="2" data-id3="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" contenteditable><?php echo $row["a"] ?></td>
</tr>
```

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', '.a_qual', function(){  
    var id = $(this).data("id23"); 
    var a_qual = $("input[type='checkbox']").val();
    edit_data(id, a_qual, "a_qual"); 
    console.log('my message' + a_qual);
});
```

Here's my edit_data function:

```
function edit_data(id, text, column_name)  
{  
    $.ajax({  
        url:"edit.php",  
        method:"POST",  
        data:{id:id, text:text, column_name:column_name},  
        dataType:"text",  
        success:function(data){   
            fetch_data();
        }  
    });  
}
```

And here's my edit.php:

```
include_once("includes/connection.php");
$sql = "UPDATE questions SET ".$_POST['column_name']."='".$_POST['text']."' 
WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'";

// echo $sql;
if(mysqli_query($connection, $sql))
{
    echo 'Data Inserted';
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing well enough to make this work and I'm really stumped after reading dozens of posts across the internet.  For some reason, I can get it to change my database value to "1" and then it gets stuck there.  In my database I have a column named "a_qual" to store the "quality" of the checkbox and it's set to a TINYINT.  Can anyone figure out my problem?

Comment: Skim through your code, I think the expected behavior of the code should be switch the value of a_qual in the database for any id will be changed between 0 and 1. uncomment the statement echo $sql to see if the sql statements are created correctly or not. copy the sql and execute in mysql separately to see there is no syntax error. If this part is good, then let us know, we will look forward to find more issue with that

Comment: That's a great idea, and I would love to try that, but my edit.php is in a separate file.  I don't know how to get it to show the echo $sql info.  It's like it executes in the background.  I don't know jquery well enough to get it to show me that.  However, I did put "alert(data);" right above "fetch_data();" in the edit_data function and got some info:  "Array ( [id] => 304  [text] => on  [column_name] => a_qual )  UPDATE questions SET a_qual='on' WHERE id='304' Data Inserted           So, it seems to be picking up 'on' instead of '1' or '0'   Any advice?

Comment: use developers tools in your browser to execute/run the edit.php isolation.

Comment: Ok, I was able to see the $sql in the alert box...so that was VERY helpful!  So, it appears my main problem is I'm not ever getting '0' from my checkbox...I always get '1'.  Could it be something I'm missing about the way checkboxes work?  I just read about having to put a hidden field with value=0 in it...could it be that simple?  I'll have to experiment later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules of checkboxes are to send the "value" when it is checked, otherwise send nothing. So to send '0', in case of not selecting the checkbox, needs to be done manually.  By saying this I mean, on your on('change',....) method, please work around a condition to see if the checkbox is checked or not and then based on that set the value of a_qual.

> var a_qual = $("input[type='checkbox']").val();

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input!  I think I have solved at least part of my problem!  Turns out to be exactly as you said.  I put these lines inside my 'change' method:          `var item = document.getElementById("a_qual");
    var a_qual = (item.checked ? 1 : 0);`       And I am now able to toggle 0 or 1 in my database!  So, that now works.  Now, I just need to get it to refresh the page and display that new info.  I altered my html a tad, so I need to work that out and I should be good to go!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand how this site works.  I've used it for YEARS, but rarely post anything.  I got pretty desperate with this one.  I was borrowing an entire system (LiveTables) and...it can be a big challenge to try to implement and successfully modify someone else's code.  I'm still a beginner in many respects, but I'm starting to make some headway thanks to sites like this and helpful people like you!  Again, thanks!

Comment: Oh, and I tried to upvote but, evidently, my ranking on this site is not high enough for it to be publicly shown?  It said it would record my upvote, but not display it.  Anyway, I see my green checkmark, so that's good.  Cheers!